# Consolidating redundant RewriteCond lines in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to consolidate multiple *RewriteCond* lines in `.htaccess` and am struggling with the syntax. Here is my code for the redirect area of my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# BEGIN page-level mobile redirects
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index.html)?$ http://m.example.com [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^page-1/$ http://m.example.com/p1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^page-2/$ http://m.example.com/p2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^page-3/$ http://m.example.com/p3 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/page-4/$ http://m.example.com/p4 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/page-5/$ http://m.example.com/p5 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END mobile redirects
```

The above solution works properly but is inefficient because there are so many redundant *ReWriteCond* lines. My goal is to have a single *RewriteCond* line apply to all of my *RewriteRule* lines. Is this possible?

I'd normally use `REQUEST_URI` to more efficiently accomplish this, but i'm unable to in this instance because we're rewriting requests for multiple similar desktop web sites with varied *URL* layouts to a single mobile web site folder.

Comment: The solution I posted does what it's supposed to, but it's inefficient because there are so many redundant RewriteCond lines. I updated my OP to more clearly illustrate what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on skip and last flags in the Apache documentation.  You can also use the regexps to fold some of the lines:

```
# BEGIN page-level mobile redirects
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}     !"android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile"
RewriteRule ^                       -                        [skip=3]
RewriteRule ^(index.html)?$         http://m.example.com     [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^page-([123])/$         http://m.example.com/p$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/page-([45])/$ http://m.example.com/p$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END mobile redirects
```

BTW, It's a misconception to think of this in runtime terms.  Yes, each regexp / rule will add 10s of μS, but the real hit in performance terms is the need to open and to read the `.htaccess` file, *any* `.htaccess` file in the first place.  Do this sort of thing for clarity and ease of maintainability.  So long as you don't shoot yourself in the foot by being "too smart", the less lines of rules, the less chance of hiding some error.